# Jquery .css() syntax

Tags: jquery, css

Why are there times when you use a ',' vs ':' to separate .CSS parameters?

for example:

```
$('#example').css("",""); vs. $('#example').css("":"");
```

I have use in this way.

```
$('#example').css("color","#000000");
$('#example').css("cursor":"pointer");
```

Comment: I'm guessing you've missed some crucial curly braces in your example: `$('#example').css({"cursor":"pointer"});` ?

Comment: Arguments passed to functions must be separated by commas. What @Pointy showed is passing *one* argument, namely an object, created by an *object literal*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The colon is only used when you have to specify multiple values. But then you have to put the values in brackets and curly brackets and separate them by a comma.
For example:

```
$('#example').css({
  'background-color' : 'yellow',
  'font-weight' : 'bolder'
});
```

Otherwise, when you only need to set one value, you use the comma:

```
$('#example').css('background-color','yellow');
```

Comment: That's actually a very imprecise answer. What do curly brackets mean?

Comment: *"The colon is only used when you have to specify multiple values."* That's not true, you can use the object form even if you're only doing one. If you're only doing one, you have the *option* of the two-argument version of the function, but you're not required to use it.

Comment: @FelixKling: curly brackets -> {

Comment: I get that. But what is their meaning in JavaScript? Btw. it is a rhetorical question (I know what this syntax means), I wanted to encourage you to improve your answer. Right now it appears that curly brackets are something "magical" in the context of parameter passing, which is not true.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: you're right, i didn't say that you _can't_ do it, but in my opinion, it's cleaner coding, because it's more defined if there are multiple or one value(s) to set.

Comment: @FelixKling: no problem :) i'm always learning ;) as far as i know curly brackets open/declare an object, right?

Comment: @melodia That's a US/UK thing – they're brackets in the UK, braces in the US. Not sure about elsewhere.

Answer (score 7):

The second way, in your second example, is a syntax error.

I think you meant:

```
$("#example").css({'cursor': 'pointer'});
```

They both have the same effect.  The second way lets you set multiple properties with one call:

```
$('#example').css({
  'cursor': 'pointer',
  'font-size': '18px'
});
```

The ".css()" function just checks the arguments you pass it.  If there are two arguments and they're both strings (or I guess if the second is a number), then it just sets a single property. If the first argument is an object, it looks at the properties of the object and treats them all as CSS properties to set.

*edit* — a thing to realize is that this has nothing in particular to do with the ".css()" function. The "{ }" notation is just basic JavaScript syntax for an object constant.  Thus:

```
var someCSS = {
  'cursor': 'pointer', 'font-size': '12px', 'border-width': '5px'
};

$('#example').css( someCSS );
```

has exactly the same effect as passing in the object directly as in the earlier examples.

Comment: thanks, yes i see the syntax error and apologize typing too fast. mostly wanted to know the difference between the two. i did read that the colon (:) is used to separate multiple class paramaters however when trying to use the following exapmple:

$('#example').css({'cursor','pointer'});

it fails and forces me to use a colon (:)

for example:

$('#example').css({'cursor':'pointer'});

which made me think it was more than just mutliple paramenters.

thoughts?

Comment: @user311166: You should read about [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_Object_Initializers). It's not at all related to functions.

Answer (score 4):

The comma separates arguments in a function call:

```
$('#example').css("color","#000000");
```

`"color"` is one argument, `"#000000"` is another.

The colon notes key-value pairs in an object.  Your second piece of code won't work; it should be:

```
$("#example").css({'cursor': 'pointer'});
```

Here you pass *one* argument to the function, which is an object. The object allows key-value pairs. In this case, this allows you to set multiple settings in one go:

```
$("#example").css({'cursor': 'pointer', 'color': '#000000'});
```

In this case, you have a Javascript object `{'cursor': 'pointer', 'color': '#000000'}` which has two key-value pairs. The relationship between key and value is denoted by the colon, while the pairs are separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `:` you would be able to set multiple properties like so:

```
$('#example').css({'background-color' : 'yellow', 'font-weight' : 'bolder'});
```

Otherwise you can only do one property.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in JQuery `css()` suports a multiple-words object or one attribute:

Using multiple-words:

```
.css({'background-color': '#ffe', 'border-left': '5px solid #ccc'})
```

it equal the:

```
.css({backgroundColor: '#ffe', borderLeft: '5px solid #ccc'})
```

Well... the ":" means that you are assigning the property. The two examples are compatible.

read this: [Css() JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2)

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery's .css(), you can either declare one property, or multiple properties, and it can take a JSON object or "property","value" for single properties.

So, you can use `$('.example').css("border","1px solid black");` but for more than 1 property, you will use a JSON object, which is done by this format :

```
{
    "border" : "1px solid black",
    "padding" : "10px"
}
```