# jQuery CSS change on IF statement

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement, selector

I'm working on a project in jQuery and I'm selecting multiple CSS to change on a condition:

```
if (jQuery('#1').is(":visible")) {
      jQuery('#2').css({"border-top":"0px", "border-bottom":"7px solid #0767B1"});    
      jQuery('#3').css({"display:table-cell"}); 
}
```

It works with only the #2 css change, but when I add #3 it isn't working anymore.

Comment: 1,2 and 3 are not valid id's. They must not start with a digit.

Comment: Check your `"`. `"display:table-cell"` should be `"display":"table-cell"`

Comment: @Fabrizio try for html4.01, wrong for html5.

Comment: Just a side note: IDs and classes cannot start with numbers. Just like variables in JavaScript.

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan & Ahmad Alfy, I know. It was just for this example, changed the names to those numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `:` out of the *quotes*:

```
jQuery('#3').css({                        //this is used for multiple values
    "display":"table-cell"
});
```

Or like:

```
jQuery('#3').css("display","table-cell"); //for single values
```

More at [Jquery .css() syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524193/jquery-css-syntax)

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
if (jQuery('#1').is(":visible")) {
      jQuery('#2').css({"border-top":"0px", "border-bottom":"7px solid #0767B1"});    
      jQuery('#3').css("display", "table-cell"); 
}
```

The jQuery .css() method can be used in two ways. You can manipulate a single attribute, which looks like `.css("attribute", "value");`, or you can manipulate multiple values, but that has a different writing: `.css({"attribute" : "value", "attribute2" : "value"});`. But you can use the second method (as you tried) also for just a single attribute, I didn't notice your small mistake but as Vucko mentioned you just forgot to surround the `:` with `"`, so this solution was what you were looking for (but it's usually for multiple arguments as you use the `{ }` brackets):

```
jQuery('#3').css({"display":"table-cell"});
```

And my recommendation was to use the single attribute notation:

> jQuery('#3').css("display", "table-cell");

Comment: Explaining is always better than just throwing a block of code at the reader and playing the "find the character I changed" game.

Comment: @Francodi Can you explain what is difference between your answer and "Pim Peters" Question.

Comment: Please add an explanation, then I happily convert my -1 into a +1.

Comment: You're right, I just thought he would see the changed line difference and yeah... that was not really helpful. Will do it better the next time I response to someone, thanks for telling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for css change using jquery

```
// For single values :
if($('#example').css('background-color','yellow')) {
    $('#1').css("display","none");
}

// For Multiple values :
if($('#example').css('background-color','yellow')) {    // Condition code
    $('#1').css("display","none");
    $('#2').css({
      'background-color' : 'yellow',
      'font-weight' : 'bolder'
    });
}
```